# How Can I Get All Users with one Role by UserManager in Mvc Core3?

Tags: .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-identity, usermanager

How can I get all users with one role by `UserManager` in Mvc Core 3? I want `UserName`, `UserId` and roles.

This is my sample code but it's not working:

```cs
var users = userManager.Users.Take(50).ToList();
var Getesroles = new List<IList<string>>();

foreach (var item in users)
{
    Getesroles.Add(userManager.GetRolesAsync(item).Result);
}
```

What is my problem?

Comment: Do you want to find users with a specific role or get all users' roles and other info?You above code gets all roles for users, what do you mean not working?

Comment: @XingZou I want to get all users with a specific role. My sample code only return roles and no roles and users together in one result.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as using `GetUsersInRoleAsync()` method from `UserManager` class?

```cs
public class UserManager<TUser> : IDisposable where TUser : class
{
    ...
    public virtual Task<IList<TUser>> GetUsersInRoleAsync(string roleName);
    ...
}
```

That should return all the users who have the specific role you pass in.